# Group by returning null

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a simple sql that is not returning the correct values in the correct format.  The data is a follows:

```
Emp    Date          totaltime
 15   2017-01-25      05:18:35
 15   2017-01-25      04:51:03
 31   2017-01-25      05:33:22
 31   2017-01-25      03:31:36
 33   2017-01-25      04:35:06
 33   2017-01-25      04:22:24
```

I have the following sql statement:

```
select emp_num, TIME_FORMAT(sum(TotalTime),'%H:%i:%s')
 from pr_hours  
 where date='2017-01-25' 
 group by emp_num
```

I get the following results:

```
Emp_num +   TIME_FORMAT(sum(TotalTime), '%H:%i:%s') '
 15     +   NULL
 31     +   NULL 
 33     +   08:57:30
```

I have tried a variations of the above sql with mix results but none with the correct data.

This is a simple sql statement and should not be this time consuming, so please point me in the correct direction.

Comment: It would help if you describe what you want to see as "correct" results.

Comment: What do you think `sum(TotalTime)` does? Why?

Comment: I am hoping the sum(TotalTime) will give me the total time, no matter the number of records,  by employee.  It is looking like the TIME_FORMAT is causing my issue.  If I remove the TIME_FORMAT the numbers are generated correctly but un-formated.  So I guess my question now is how can I format the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select emp_num, sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(TotalTime)))
 from pr_hours  
 where date='2017-01-25' 
 group by emp_num
```

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks.  Best for me to go back and read the documentation again.